# Visual Studio 2012 update 4 and TFS 2013 update 3 are not compatible

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I want to create a new team project from `Visual studio 2012 (Professional - Ultimate)` update 4 in TFS 2013 express update 3 and I get below error however I can work on other projects that already exitst on the TFS

[image]

Comment: `you can work on other projects` is something completely different than creating a new team project. As the error message tells you, you need the rights to create one. That is a TFS permission setting

Comment: TFS and VS2012 are on the same machine.

Comment: As @Mark says, you need to be a TFS admin to create new Team Projects. In addition there are a number of under the hood changes from TFS 2012 to TFS 2013 so it's probably safer to use Team Explorer 2013 to create the new team project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. You need to have VS 2013 (any release) in order to be able to create projects on TFS 2013 (any release). 
To sum up, if you want to create new TFS project then major version of the client (Visual Studio) should be greater or equal to the major version of the server.

Here's the list of working combinations for creating new projects or customizing existing ones (using witadmin tool):

```
VS 2013 (RTM, Update 1-3) -> TFS 2010/2012/2013 (RTM or any of the updates)
VS 2012 (RTM, Update 1-4) -> TFS 2005/2008/2010/2012 (RTM or any of the updates)
VS 2010 (RTM, SP1) - > TFS 2005/2008/2010 (RTM or any of the updates)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to **create** a Team Project, your Team Explorer version should match the server version.

In order to **connect** to a Team Project, you just need a compatible version. They do not need to match the server's.